# How do I determine and fix why I can not output LPCM from XBMC?

Tags: sound, realtek, xbmc

I have a fresh installation of ubuntu 14.04 on an Intel motherboard with Realtek ALC662-VC-based audio.  I want to output LPCM no matter what audio format XBMC encounters, but LPCM is not a choice.  I believe I may be missing the proper codecs and/or drivers, but don't know how to narrow down the problem and fix it.

I do not think this is a problem related to XBMC, because Windows installation on the same machine has the option available...

**cat /proc/asound/cards**

```
 0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
                      HDA Intel MID at 0xfe420000 ira 45
```

**lspci -v**

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0038
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at fe420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

**lsmod | grep snd**

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46207  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    61438  1 
snd_hda_intel          52355  0 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69238  11             snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  1 snd
```

**aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 1: ALC662 rev1 Digital [ALC662 rev1 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

One final thought, the motherboard has a display port connector vs. an actual HDMI connector.

Comment: You really need to give more info on your setup, for example, the output of `aplay -l` to show whether the card was recognized correctly. Can you output LPCM with any other linux multimedia application?

Comment: @noleti updated the question with more information.  I don't use another multimedia application (but will try anything suggested).

Comment: I think it might be possible, as xmbc should support lpcm, see http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Talk:PulseAudio

With intel hardware, I found the following very helpful: `wget www.alsa-project.org/hda-analyzer.py -O run.py &&
sudo python run.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is not possible...  To add passthrough of AC3 and DTS remove pulseaudio

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: So this is one that it works for you, right?

Comment: No this is not what I want, but I believe what I want is not possible.  I want all the possible surround encodings to be outputted as LPCM....

Comment: Then it's better to unaccept it, to get more interest for your question. they think its already solved.